# Custom user role that can only edit specific (non-custom-type) page and all child pages

Tags: wp-admin, users, child-pages, page-specific-settings

My site has several static pages and several custom post types. I'm trying to create a custom user role called `students` and give students access to ONLY certain custom post types and certain specific static pages.

I understand how to do this with custom post types by using `add_cap()` and populating the 'capability_type' and 'map_meta_cap' fields passed to `register_post_type` for that custom post type.

**However, I don't understand how to do this for generic pages (which are not custom, but have been populated with different content)**. Specifically, I would like to take a parent page called `internal-resources` and give the `student` users editing capability for that specific page. There are some child pages of the `internal-resources` page they should be able to edit too. Finally, I would like them to be able to create new child pages under `internal-resources`. However, other static pages like `Research` and `People` they should NOT be able to edit. This shouldn't be too difficult, right?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: The cleanest solution would indeed be to make the specific page trees, that you want to be edited by the student users, a custom post type. So there is a point to be made to just do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way in WordPress to assign the capability for editing (or any action) a specific post to a role.

However, you can filter capabilities checks and change them on the fly using the [`map_meta_cap`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/map_meta_cap/).

When handling post permissions, WordPress ultimately deals in just 4 capabilties:

- `edit_post`
- `read_post`
- `delete_post`
- `publish_post`

Then whenever an action is performed on a post it maps these capabilities to the 'primitive' capabilities. These are the capabilities you'll be more familiar with:

- `publish_posts`
- `edit_posts`
- `edit_others_posts`
- `edit_private_posts`
- `edit_published_posts`
- `read`
- `read_private_posts`
- `delete_posts`
- `delete_private_posts`
- `delete_published_posts`
- `delete_others_posts`

There is also `create_posts`, but as far as I can tell this is only used in some REST endpoints and for controlling whether some UI appears. When saving a post `create_posts` is mapped to `edit_posts`.

What `map_meta_cap()` does is that when someone tries to edit a post it determines which primitive capability is required.

So if a user tries to edit a post, `map_meta_cap()` checks if they are the author of that post. If they are then the `edit_post` meta capability will be mapped to `edit_posts`. If they are not the author it will be mapped to `edit_others_posts`. WordPress will then check if the user has the mapped capability and respond accordingly.

So if you want to change permissions on a per-page basis, you need to filter `map_meta_cap` to change the way it assigns the meta capabilities.

In your example, you want to let users `edit_page` for the Internal Resources page (and others), but not edit any other pages. This is a little bit tricky because to do this they need access to the Pages menu in the Dashboard. So you'll need to grant your `student` role the `edit_pages` and `publish_pages` capabilities, and then use the filter to revoke those capabilities on a page-by-page basis:

```
function wpse_293259_map_meta_cap( $required_caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
    if ( in_array( $cap, ['edit_post', 'publish_post'] ) ) {
        $page_id = $args[0]; // The ID of the post being edited.
        $student_pages = [1,2,3]; // The IDs of the pages students are allowed to edit.

        /**
         * If the page being edited is not one students can edit, check if the user
         * is a student. If they are, set the required capabilities to 'do_not_allow'
         * to prevent them editing.
         */
        if ( ! in_array( $page_id, $student_pages ) ) {
            $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

            if ( in_array( 'students', $user->roles ) ) {
                $required_caps = ['do_not_allow'];
            }
        }
    }

    return $required_caps;
}
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'wpse_293259_map_meta_cap', 10, 4 );
```

This will prevent publishing or editing of pages that aren't in the `$student_pages`.

I have not been able to figure out a good way to allow users to publish pages but only if they're a child of a particular page. Every mix of editing and publishing capabilities I've tried has resulted in weird behaviour. I don't think child pages are a good way to manage permissions because they are a thing that can be changed on the page editor. This means that you would be changing permissions between publishing a post and being redirected back to edit it.

You might be best off using the technique I described to allow editing of the Internal Resources page, but then break the sub-pages out into a separate post type with its own permissions.

Comment: I hadn't seen the possible duplicate comment when posting (I had been writing this for, er, a while).